# Integral relations when using different measures.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ a measurable space and $\mu$,$\nu$ two non-negative measures s.t $\mu \geq \nu$. Does it hold that $\int_E f \, d\mu \geq \int_E f \,d\nu $ where $E \in \mathcal{M}$. I suspect it should hold if $f$ is nonnegative on $E$. Can we derive a similar result generally for signed measures? Also if $p$ a third measure s.t. $p=\mu+\nu$, under what conditions we have $\int_Efdp=\int_Efd\mu+\int_Efd\nu$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess you could prove it first for simple functions, and then use MCT to extend to all non-negative functions using "measure theoretic induction." That last statement is probably true for all $f\in L^{+}$ or $f \in L^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, just to clarify, by $\mu\leq \nu$ I expect you mean $\mu(A)\leq \nu(A)$ for $A$. We therefore have that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous wrt $\nu$ (written $\mu\ll\nu$, and why I'm asking about the meaning of your inequality) and so there is a function in $L^1(\nu)$, $\frac{\mathrm d\mu}{\mathrm d\nu}$ such that $$\int_E \frac{\mathrm d\mu}{\mathrm d\nu} \mathrm d \nu = \int_E \mathrm d\mu =\mu(E).$$ Furthermore, $\frac{\mathrm d\mu}{\mathrm d\nu}\leq 1$ a.e. as otherwise, there is a set with more $\mu$ measure than $\nu$ measure. Also the derivative gives us a much stronger result, namely the first equality below.
$$ \int_E f \mathrm d\mu = \int_E f \frac{\mathrm d\mu}{\mathrm d\nu} \mathrm d \nu \leq \int_E f \mathrm d \nu$$ We get the second equality from our bound on the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

For signed measures, you'd get the same result so long as the derivative is so bounded.

For your final question, the answer is always.

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ non-negative?

Comment: Only in the second inequality in the second equation block. Besides that, for signed measures, you'd be better off just decomposing into positive and negative parts and working things out that way.